# Nodejs Multer On Success get The return value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I'm tring to upload an image with NodeJS + ExpressJS + Multer but im facing this problem that i cant get the return value from the uplode function of Multer so i can work on setting the image name on my database or throw an error

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");
const photoModel = require("../../models/Photo");

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./client/public/uploads/",
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, "IMAGE-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 1000000 }
}).single("myImage");

router.post("/upload/:row", async (req, res) => {
  const id = "1";
  const { row } = req.params;
  const result = await upload(req, res, err => {
    console.log("Request ---", req.body);
    console.log("Request file ---", req.file); //Here you get file.
    /*Now do where ever you want to do*/
    // if (!err) return res.send(200).end();
    if (!err) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  console.log("result ", result);
  if (result) {
    const check = photoModel.SetImage(id, row);
    if (check) console.log(check);
    else {
      console.log(check);
    }
  }
});
```

i expect to get the result return true or false but the actual output is result  undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did find a soultion for my problem and set multer as middleware

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");
const photoModel = require("../../models/Photo");
const fs = require("file-system");

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    const { id } = req.user;
    const { row } = req.params;
    const dir = `./client/public/uploads/${id}/`;
    fs.exists(dir, exists => {
      if (!exists) {
        return fs.mkdir(dir, error => cb(error, dir));
      }
      return cb(null, dir);
    });
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    const { row } = req.params;
    console.log(row);
    if (row === "profile_Image")
      return callback(null, "profile" + path.extname(file.originalname));
    else
      return callback(
        null,
        "IMAGE-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
      );
  }
});

// @route   Post api/profle/upload
// @desc    upload user images
// @access  Private
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
router.post("/upload/:row", [auth, upload.single("myImage")], (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;
  const { row } = req.params;
  const id = req.user.id;
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error("Please upload a file");
    error.httpStatusCode = 400;
    return next(error);
  } else {
    const check = photoModel.SetImage(id, row, file.filename);
    if (check) {
      return res.json({
        success: true,
        errorMsg: "Your image hass been uploaded"
      });
    } else {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        errorMsg: "There is an error on upload image"
      });
    }
  }
});
```

hope that can help someone in the future ;)